# How to darken the area around the field to be scanned?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, layout, graphics

How to darken the area around the field to be scanned?

I would like the view as in the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hXb3.png). I have a frame around, but I do not know how to dim the area around. I use google vision.

[[image]]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play around with the frame area's alpha (transparency).

For example, you can set the `android:background` attribute to `android:background="#80000000"`. The first two digits of the hex color code is the alpha value of the background. This will give you 50% alpha.

You can do this programatically `frameArea.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"))`.

https://css-tricks.com/8-digit-hex-codes/